# How to get value from input in table column and sum them up?

Tags: html, jquery

I am making an entry list that will automatically add up the amount and show the total amount at the bottom. I am trying to implement onchange into the function but unsure how to do it. My current code only get to sum up the amount if the value is fixed and need to refresh page.

Thanks in advance.

```
var rows = $("#data tr:gt(0)");
var tamount;

rows.children("td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
 tamount += parseInt($(this).html());
});

$("#total_amount").html(tamount);
```

```
| No | Description | Amount |
| -- | ----------- | ------ |
| 1  | abc         | 2.50   |
| 2  | efg         | 1.90   |
| 3  | tyu         | 5.00   |
| 4  | mno         | 7.90   |

--------------------
Total Amount : 17.30
--------------------
```

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="descrpt"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="descrpt"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="descrpt"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <h5>Total Amount :<input type="number" name="total_amount" readonly></h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[name="total_amount"]').val(calcSum());
       $('input[name="amount"]').change(function () { 
         $('input[name="total_amount"]').val(calcSum());
       });
   });

function calcSum() {
  var tamount = 0;
  $('input[name="amount"]').each(function() {
    tamount += parseInt(($(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0));
  });
  return tamount;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="descrpt"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="descrpt"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="descrpt"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="amount"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <h5>Total Amount :<input type="number" name="total_amount" readonly></h5>
</div>
```

Explanation:

- Instead of getting the child elements, you can directly use
  `$('input[name="amount"]')` to refer to each input element
- `$('input[name="amount"]').each()` will iterate over each number
  field
- I created a new function `calcSum()` to do the calculation part.
- You should use `.val()` for input elements instead of `.html()`
- Note, `change()` will require you to lose focus from the field, alternately, you can use `keyup()`

No change in html required.

Comment: First of all, thanks man!! Your code work out great. Just wanna share, I have made some changes of your code to make it output number with decimal places.

parseInt -> parseFloat
return tamount; -> return tamount.toFixed(2);